# System.Xml.Xsl: How do I redirect output produced by xsl:message elements to my trace listeners?

Tags: .net, xslt

I know about `Console.SetOut`, but can't figure out what I should pass to this method.

Comment: This is specific for your XSLT processor. There is nothing in XSLT language to enforce this. That's why the `xsltprocessor` tag.

Comment: I consider that the subject of XSLT is wider than just XSLT language itself. But OK, I'll restore the `xsltprocessor` tag, although its meaning isn't obvious enough without explanation in the tag wiki.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if question nor answers include any reference to XSLT instructions, then it's not an XSLT question.

Comment: My question has the reference to xsl:message! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Console.SetOut` will set stream for console outputs.
Use `XsltMessageEncountered` event of `XsltArgumentList` class and write the message to Trace listenres using `Trace.Write`.

```
void TestTransform()
{
    XsltArgumentList xsltargs = new XsltArgumentList();
    xsltargs.XsltMessageEncountered += new XsltMessageEncounteredEventHandler(OnXsltMessageEncountered);

    XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
    //....some code to load xslt and other stuffs. Pass the xsltargs to transform
}

void OnXsltMessageEncountered(object sender, XsltMessageEncounteredEventArgs e)
{
    //write the message to Trace.
    Trace.Write(e.Message);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I've already found this solution. This is supported by XslCompiledTransform only. Console.SetOut is the only way to do this with XslTransform.